# Proof $e^{\sqrt2 \pi i n}\not=e^{\sqrt2 \pi i m}$ for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\not=m$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I think I was able to prove this, but I am not sure why another proof attempt went wrong.

What worked:
$$e^{\sqrt2 \pi i n}=e^{\sqrt2 \pi i m}$$ would mean
$$ \sqrt2\pi in+2\pi ik = \sqrt2\pi im$$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, right?
Doing some algebra this is just equal to
$$n+\sqrt2k=m$$ what is obviously wrong for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}, k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Does this proof work or am I missing something?

However, at first I tried to pull the $\sqrt2m$-th root on both sides
$$(e^{\sqrt2\pi in})^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2m}}=(e^{\sqrt2\pi im})^{\frac{1}{\sqrt2m}}$$
what gives us
$$ e^{\pi i\frac{n}{m}}=e^{\pi i}$$
what obviously gives wrong solutions like $n=3, m=1$.
I wonder why this second approach does not work? Where do I overlook a fault?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

José already answered your first question and I agree, what you did was fine. Let me address why your second approach doesn't work. When dealing with complex numbers, you have to be careful when taking non-integer powers. The "rule"
$$(z^x)^y = z^{xy}$$
is not true in general. For example, consider $e^{2\pi i} = 1$ and take the square root. According to the above "rule", you would get
$$-1 = e^{\pi i} = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{2}} = 1^{\frac{1}{2}} = 1,$$
which is clearly nonsense. That's why your second approach didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

What you did is fine, until you reach $n+\sqrt2k=m$. Then, you could have said that, unless $k=0$, then you have$$\sqrt2=\frac{m-n}k,$$which is impossible, since $\sqrt2$ is irrational.